# Redirecting output to file shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to make a script that will take an input from a user (a name and username) then direct that input to a text file named with that username. The code I have below will create the file, however doesn't direct any of the data into the file. 
Can anybody help me with this problem? Thanks

```
echo "What is your name?"
read name
echo "What is your chosen username?"
read username
cd user_records
$name >> "$username".txt
$username >> "$username".txt
```

Comment: Add `echo`... `echo $name >>... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lohmar gave the answer, but you need to echo the variable.  Your code is trying to execute $name and $username, but you need to use it as data, not a command.

```
echo -n "What is your name? "
read name
echo -n "What is your chosen username? "
read username
cd user_records
echo "$name" >> "$username".txt
echo "$username" >> "$username".txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Few comments:

- You could to use the `-p` parameter to read.
- Also always use the `-r` unless you know why don't want it.
- you should check the success of the `cd` - what if it is unsuccessful?
- always quote your variables

```
#!/bin/bash
err(){ echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }

udir="./user_records"

read -r -p  'What is your name?> ' name
read -r -p  'What is your chosen username?> ' username
cd "$udir" || err "Can't cd to $udir" || exit 1
printf "%s\n%s\n" "$name" "$username" >> "$username.txt"
```

or maybe you don't need `cd`, in such case you can write

```
err(){ echo "$@" >&2; return 1; }

udir="./user_records"

read -r -p  'What is your name?> ' name
read -r -p  'What is your chosen username?> ' username
[[ -d "$udir" ]] || err "The $udir doesn't exists" || exit 1
printf "%s\n%s\n" "$name" "$username" >> "$udir/$username.txt"
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a go!

Comment: Yeah, I had a lot of other stuff, but deleted it-- it felt like over kill for what was asked.  I dunno.

Comment: btw, my standard cd error checking is `cd dir || { echo "error" >&2; exit 40; }` Stringing two || isn't needed.  Also, you can do `read -rp "this is my prompt: "` and save some spaces :-)

Comment: @jm666 you missed my point.  I actually have a function library that has a log() and err() that also prepends the string with a date/time string.  My point was that you are doing two OR commands, instead of wrapping your error message and exit in curly-braces.